# How to change the format of time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I've an input of type time, when I click on it I can select an hour from 1-12, mins and AM/PM.  [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXEPW.png)

When I render the selection it appears in 24-hour format. However, instead, I want it to be in a 12-hour format.
I'm working on a react-redux app.

```js
<input type='time' 
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({
            time: e.target.value
          })}
          value={this.state.time} />
```

```js
state = {
    time: ''
  }
  render = () => {
    return (
      <span>{time}</span>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function for changing time format:

```
const timeConvertor = (time) => {
  // first checks the correct time format and then split it into components
  time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

  if (time.length > 1) { // If the time format is correct
    time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
    time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; // Set AM/PM based on given hour
    time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // change the hour based on AM/PM
  }
  return time.join (''); // return new time format as a String
}
```

for example:

```
timeConvertor('20:50:00'); // will return '8:50:00PM'
```

Comment: I don't understand it.

Comment: @QatrEl-Nada it is a function and you can pass a time in 24 hr format as String input and receive time in 12 hr format as an output.